# submit form with <button type="submit"> to the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, form-submit

I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name_car" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Add car" />
</form>
```

then to fetch the field use:

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $name_car=   $_POST['name_car'];
    ....
}
```

So far so good. Now do the same with a button. Something of this kind (in the code below) and that the process to fetch the data is equal.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name_car" />
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="wizard-submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition you are testing for to see if the form has been submitted is no longer true.

Original HTML:

```
name="submit"
```

New HTML:

```
name="wizard-submit"
```

The test in PHP:

```
if($_POST['submit'])
```

---

Additionally, your button has no value attribute, you'll need to add one (since otherwise `$_POST['submit']` still isn't true)

You should also add some content to the button so that people know what it does.

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="something">Submit</button>
```

Comment: When do I submit it does not enter the if ($_POST ['submit']). And since changed the name of the button

Comment: What does your revised HTML look like?

Comment: `if ($_POST ['submit'])` won’t be true, because you have given your button no `value`.

Comment: … which I did mention in this answer (and is why I asked for the revised HTML to see if the OP had read all of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a button instead of input type submit replace `$_POST["submit"]` with your button name `$_POST["wizard-submit"]`.

Then if you want your form be single page, change the form file extension to php and include your form process code in it.

**NOTICE:** use `isset` instead of vanilla `if` condition:

```php
if ($_POST["submit"])
```

replace with:

```php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that. Just put the path to the form in 'action' field.

Comment: I do not need to fill anything in the action field because it will be on the same page

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

did you try with the

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
```

now the if condition only will be true if there are data, if it's null will be false.